# Getting Internal Server Error (500) - CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my CodeIgniter project I need to insert data into db table, I am having

> Internal server error (500)

issues to add data to database using Ajax.

My Ajax code is below,

```
$("#rsvp_form").validate({
    rules: {
        uname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        uemail: "required",
        umessage: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 100
        }
    },
    messages: {
        uname: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least 8 characters required!")
        },
        uemail: "Please enter your email",
        umessage: {
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than 100 characters!")
        },
    },
    // ajax request
    submitHandler: function (form) {

        var formData = {
            'user_name': $('input[name=uname]').val(),
            'user_email': $('input[name=uemail]').val(),
            'user_wish': $('input[name=umessage]').val()
        };

        // loader
        $(".loader").show();

        // ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Welcome/create_wish",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                // if send data successfull
                if (data.status === 'success') {

                    $(".loader").hide();
                    $(form).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".form-success").show("slow");
                    }, 300);

                    // if send data something wrong 
                } else if (data.status === 'error') {

                    $(".loader").hide();
                    $(form).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".form-error").show("slow");
                    }, 300);
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    }

});
```

My `Welcome` Controller function is below : ,

```
public function create_wish() {
    $this->load->model("model_wishes");
    $data = array(
    'user_name' => $this->input->post('uname'),
    'user_email' => $this->input->post('uemail'),
    'user_wish' => $this->input->post('umessage')
    );
    $this->model_wishes->createWish($data);
}
```

`model_wishes` Model is here,

```
function createWish($data) {
    $this->db->insert("wishes", $data);
}
```

`welcome_message` View is,

```
<form id="rsvp_form" action="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="post-name">Name</label>
        <input autocomplete='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="post-email">Email</label>
        <input autocomplete='email' type="email" class="form-control" id="uemail" name="uemail" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 margin-b-2">
        <label for="post-message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="umessage" rows="5" name="umessage"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-left mb-0">
        <button id="btn-create" type="submit" class="button-medium btn btn-default fill-btn">Post Wish</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When `Post Wish` button is clicked getting `XHR failed loading: POST` and an error

```
POST http://localhost/CodeIgniterProj/index.php/Welcome/create_wish 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please let me know what actually force to internal server error, and how could I fix this Issue.

Comment: If you are in a development environment change the `ENVIRONMENT` constant in your `index.php` file to `development` to enable errors.

Comment: try by setting `url: "<?=site_url('Welcome/create_wish'); ?>"`, in your ajax and also `print_r($this->input->post());`  in your `create_wish()` method to check what u get in post

Comment: add SetEnv CI_ENV development in your .htaccess file to see errors.

Comment: @pradeep nothing happened

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happend see ur browser's network tab to see the output or for the error

Comment: @pradeep Column 'user_wish' cannot be null

Comment: so debug why `user_wish` is empty by using `print_r($this->input->post());die;` in `create_wish ()` method

Comment: Like this `public function create_wish() { print_r($this->input->post());die;}` and see ur browser's network tab to see the output

Comment: @pradeep thanx I found. inside ajax umessage should be textarea

Comment: instead of individual input use `var formData  = $(form).serialize();` to get all input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your `submitHandler` code should be like this :

```
submitHandler: function (form) 
{
  var formData = $(form).serialize();
  $(".loader").show();
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=site_url('Welcome/create_wish'); ?>",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

And your controller `create_wish` should be like this :

```
public function create_wish() 
{
    $this->load->model("model_wishes");
    $user_name = $this->input->post('uname'));
    $user_email = $this->input->post('uemail');
    $user_wish = $this->input->post('umessage');

    $data = array(
      'user_name' => $user_name,
      'user_email' => $user_email,
      'user_wish' => $user_wish
    );
    $this->model_wishes->createWish($data);
    $response = array('status' => 'success');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You are using wrong post input, please check below updated code**

```
public function create_wish() {
    $this->load->model("model_wishes");
    $data = array(
    'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
    'user_email' => $this->input->post('user_email'),
    'user_wish' => $this->input->post('user_wish')
    );
    $this->model_wishes->createWish($data);
}
```

Comment: How it can be `<input autocomplete='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" required />`

Comment: @ChyperX because you are using ajax 
var formData = {
            'user_name': $('input[name=uname]').val(),
            'user_email': $('input[name=uemail]').val(),
            'user_wish': $('input[name=umessage]').val()
        };

Comment: @ChyperX try print_r($_POST) in controller function .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **base_url** use the **site_url**

```
site_url('Welcome/create_wish')
```